# Systemd startup script for docker container not working

Tags: docker, systemd

I used [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/919059/533049) answer as a guide to help me writer a startup script for systemd to start my Jenkins container when my machine boots up. However, the script is not working. Here is the script:

```
[Unit]
Description=Docker container that houses the Jenkins build service.
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Group=docker
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker start jenkins
ExecStop=/usr/bin/docker stop jenkins

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I placed it in `/etc/systemd/system/jenkins.service`.

When I run `sudo systemctl start jenkins`, nothing happens. No errors or anything printed out, and the container does not start (if I run `docker ps`, there are no containers listed as running).

I can run `/usr/bin/docker start jenkins` from the command line manually and it starts perfectly fine, so the issue seems to be in the way I've written the script, but I can't figure out why it's not working as expected. Any help is appreciated.

**Update:**

I've updated the script by changing the `ExecStart` and `ExecStop` values to be `/bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/docker start jenkins'` and `/bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/docker stop jenkins'`, respectively, but that still didn't work.

**Update 2:**

I updated the `ExecStart` and `ExecStop` by removing the `/bin/sh -c "..."` and just enclosing the command in double quotes, but now I get an interesting output in `sudo systemctl status jenkins`:

```
$ sudo systemctl status jenkins
● jenkins.service - Docker container that houses the Jenkins build service.
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/jenkins.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2017-12-03 12:20:39 EST; 10s ago
  Process: 1513 ExecStop=/usr/bin/docker stop jenkins (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
  Process: 1511 ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker start jenkins (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
 Main PID: 1511 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Dec 03 12:20:39 evt-jenkins systemd[1]: Started Docker container that houses the Jenkins build service..
Dec 03 12:20:39 evt-jenkins systemd[1]: jenkins.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Dec 03 12:20:39 evt-jenkins systemd[1]: jenkins.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=203
Dec 03 12:20:39 evt-jenkins systemd[1]: jenkins.service: Unit entered failed state.
Dec 03 12:20:39 evt-jenkins systemd[1]: jenkins.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Is there a way I can see **exactly** what is failing? These error codes aren't really indicative of anything.

**Update 3:**

Okay, so I stared from the beginning again and removed the quotes. The `jenkins.service` file now reads exactly as it does at the top of the question. When I reload systemd, and start the service, this is the output of `sudo systemctl status jenkins`:

```
$ sudo systemctl status jenkins
● jenkins.service - Docker container that houses the Jenkins build service.
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/jenkins.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Sun 2017-12-03 12:31:59 EST; 2s ago
  Process: 1683 ExecStop=/usr/bin/docker stop jenkins (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 1594 ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker start jenkins (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 1594 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Dec 03 12:31:59 evt-jenkins systemd[1]: Started Docker container that houses the Jenkins build service..
Dec 03 12:31:59 evt-jenkins docker[1594]: jenkins
Dec 03 12:31:59 evt-jenkins docker[1683]: jenkins
```

So systemd not only reports a successful run of the script, but it also shows the right output of starting a container by its name (rather than its SHA). But when I run `docker ps`, there is nothing listed!! Might I remind you that when I run the docker command manually, the container runs just fine.

Any thoughts? Systemd is proving itself to be quite difficult to work with.

**Update 4:**

Okay, so I just noticed something very strange going on here. If you notice in the above snippet (the output of `sudo systemctl status jenkins`), you'll notice that the PID of the `ExecStart` is 1594, and the PID of the `ExecStop` is 1683. Now further down in the output, you'll see that the output of the `ExecStart` is coming first, *before* the `ExecStop`. I'm not sure if this would be because of output buffering, or if systemd is making the `ExecStart` run before the `ExecStop`.

Comment: Usually containers are initially created with `docker run` whereas `docker start` is used to start already-created, stopped containers. Does your container already exist?

Comment: Yes, it does. Running `docker start jenkins` works fine, and I can see the container when I run `docker ps -a` before I start it.

Comment: It would be better to use docker-compose or the like as stated below.

Answer (score 2):

Is there a reason why you try to do this with a systemd startup script and not with the docker mechanisms like `restart: always`?

We are using docker-compose.yml and it looks like this:

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2'

services:
  jenkins:
    image: ###OWN_JENKINS_IMAGE###
    restart: always
    mem_limit: 2100m
    networks:
      - web
      - dockerhub
    environment:
      - "REVERSE_PROXY_PORT=8080"
      - "REVERSE_PROXY_HOSTNAME=####INTERNAL_HOSTNAME####"
      - "X_PROXY_PORT=443"
      - "X_PROXY_SCHEME=https"
      - "X_PROXY_NAME=####INTERNAL_HOSTNAME####"
    volumes:
      - ./data/jenkins:/var/jenkins_home
      - ./data/ssh/:/var/ssh/
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker
      - ./data/volumes/lib64/libdevmapper.so.1.02:/usr/lib/libdevmapper.so.1.02
      - ./data/volumes/lib64/libdw.so.1:/usr/lib/libdw.so.1
      - ./data/volumes/lib64/libgcrypt.so.11:/usr/lib/libgcrypt.so.11
      - ./data/volumes/lib64/libsystemd-id128.so.0:/usr/lib/libsystemd-id128.so.0
      - ./data/volumes/lib64/libsystemd-journal.so.0:/usr/lib/libsystemd-journal.so.0

networks:
  web:
    external:
      name: web
  dockerhub:
    external:
      name: ####INTERNAL_HOSTNAME####
```

After starting the image with `docker-compose up -d` it will be restarted when there is a problem and as soon as the whole server below restarts.

Comment: Having Docker itself start the container is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with using Docker to start the container, and using the restart: always option.

As for the script & logging:

- Are you overriding any defaults for the docker daemon?  You might want to consider using an override file with just the non-default values rather than editing the systemd config files themselves.
- Your output from systemctl: have you tried setting StandardOutput=tty to see what is happening as it happens?
- Other logs: do you see any errors in other logs on your system such as /var/log/syslog or /var/log/messages? For systemd the default output for stderr is syslog.

I'm asking this because in my Unix/Linux experience you need to view the logs when system actions do not add up.

For more information on using Docker with systemd, you can check out this [wiki](https://www.aquasec.com/wiki/display/containers/Controlling+Docker+With+systemd).